# How to insert mesh into other object so I can paint them indepentently?

Tags: mesh

I'm new in Blender. I have my cube and let's say I would like to make a simple face on one of its faces and later paint it with different colours and animate. Is there any way to insert these meshes into cube's face? All solutions or other ideas would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: you can assign a material to each object, and then if you Join (ctrl-J) them into a single object the correct faces will have to correct materials (will become a multi-material slot object).

Comment: You can align and use a boolean modifier (union, I would think) on the primary (Cube?) mesh.

Comment: use a boolean (choose Intersect) on each of the sub-object: to get only an outline image (2D) on the Cube face. You might want to use the Solidify on each object with a positive offset if you want a bit more surface of the sub-object to show.

Comment: For animation, you may want to parent the sub-objects to the Cube object, so that they move *relative* to (follow along with) any animation of the Cube

Comment: Thanks for help @james_t